# woocommerce/wordpress set maximum cart total

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

I can't find any plugins that allow me to set rules I need to cart.
I found plugins which allow to set rules that let you set max/min purchases (only calculates total of products) but doesn't take into account total price of products+fees+shipping (total cart).
Anyone know any solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the plugin? Wherever they calculate the total of products there might be a filter where you can add the fees, shipping etc yourself

Comment: I found a way to "bypass" by setting fee+shipping static and put max value on product total. But this will only work for my site, so not sure how someone else will proceed.

Comment: You can answer your own question. Other users may find it handy. Not sure what you mean by 'only work for my site'.

Answer (score 0):

As advised I can answer my own question.

First off my query was about setting maximum price allowed to a cart total, not just product total.
eg.max Total products+shipping+fees=100

Here's the solution:
I found a plugin called min "Min and Max Purchase for WooCommerce".If you set your fee (if you have that implemented) and shipping to static eg. $1 fee and $1 shipping all the time.

You can then set maximum total price of products to [desired maximum price to set - (static shipping cost+ static fee)= total max price to set for products]

From example on top deired maximum [$100 desired maximum total-($1 shipping+$1 fee)=$98 total max price to set for products]

This will only work for your eCommerce website IF your shipping cost are static and not affected by weight of products.